# Legacy Sql equivalent to TABLE_QUERY(dataset, expr) in standard sql

Tags: google-bigquery

Can anyone help me with understanding the equivalent of TABLE_QUERY(dataset, expr) in Standard Sql.

I found this on google docs for Legacy Sql:

```
#legacySQL
SELECT
  speed
FROM (TABLE_QUERY([myproject-1234:mydata],
                  'table_id CONTAINS "oo" AND length(table_id) >= 4'))
```

I did not find the equivalent for above in Standard SQl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#standardSQL
SELECT speed
FROM `myproject-1234.mydata.*`
WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX LIKE '%oo%'
AND LENGTH(_TABLE_SUFFIX) >= 4
```

Important: using just `*` as a wildcard for whole table name as in `myproject-1234.mydata.*` is the worst case performance wise

Ideally your table suffix should be as narrow as you can use - like for example `myproject-1234.mydata.myprefix_`

Read more about [Wildcard Tables](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/wildcard-table-reference)

Also, here you can read more about [Migrating legacy SQL table wildcard functions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/wildcard-table-reference#migrating_legacy_sql_table_wildcard_functions)